# Convert integer to logical array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I want to convert an integer `i` to a logical vector with an i-th non-zero element. That can de done with `1:10 == 2`, which returns

```
0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Now, I want to vectorize this process for each row. Writing `repmat(1:10, 2, 1) == [2 5]'` I expect to get

```
0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

But instead, this error occurs:

> Error using  == 
>   Matrix dimensions must agree.

Can I vectorize this process, or is a `for` loop the only option?

Comment: @johnny5 It's not, but it's very ill-formed and unclear. The answer by beaker below clarifies what OP wants, and it's even on-topic.

Comment: In general, be careful about expecting 1s and 0s to be treated as logical. Consider: `>> foo = 1:10;
>> foo([1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0])
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. 
>> foo(logical([1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]))
ans =
     1     3     5     7     9`

Answer (score 9):

You can use `bsxfun`:

```
>> bsxfun(@eq, 1:10, [2 5].')
ans =

   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

Note the transpose `.'` on the second vector; it's important.

Comment: Mentalist badge, +1 ;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak I've been working out with my Jedi Force Trainer.

Comment: For people using octave, [broadcasting](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html) allows to write simply `(1:10) == [2 5].'`

Comment: @ederag Very true, and I actually generated the sample above on Octave. But I didn't want to confuse things as the question is only tagged MATLAB and not Octave.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use `eye` and create a logical matrix that is `n x n` long, then use the indices to index into the rows of this matrix:

```
n = 10;
ind = [2 5];

E = eye(n,n) == 1;
out = E(ind, :);
```

We get:

```
>> out

out =

     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another possibility using indexing:

```
n = 10;
ind = [2 5];
x=zeros(numel(ind),n);
x(sub2ind([numel(ind),n],1:numel(ind),ind))=1;
```